# font awesome v5 :before not working

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

For some reason I can't seem to get this working.

In my css I have:

```
.styled-ul-list.media-nav {
  li:before {
      content: "\f02e";
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 solid";
  }
}
```

and then i have added this script:

```
<script>
    window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
        searchPseudoElements: true
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try just - font-family: 'FontAwesome';

Comment: yes that does not work anymore in the new version

Answer (score 0):

```
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

I think you should include this stuff.It's in the file `web-fonts-with-css/css/fa-solid.css`.If you are using sass or less you can extend it.